# Find last row in Excel and copy the values to new spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Hi can anyone help me in getting the desired output?

I need to retrieve the last row  values from an excel and copy the data from the cells onto separate worksheet into two different columns.
Best Regards

Comment: Check this URL to get last row: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba. And you can search how to copy and paster the rows on google.

Comment: Hi Paresh, i have managed to get the Last Row however when i am struggling to retrieve two columns information from that row. for example if my last row is 21, i need the values from E21 and H21 copied on to different Spreadsheet. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it like you always want to retrieve data from last cell and last cell + 2? As in your eg shows E21 and H21.

Comment: Yes, basically if my Last row is say 11 then i need data from E11 & H11 and say if my Last row is 19 then i need to retrieve the data from E19 & H19

Answer (score 1):

Once you got the LastRow of specific column, you can use the following code to get the value of cells you want:

For Eg: If A is the specific column and variable LastRow contains the row count then,

```
strA = Range("A" & LastRow).Value 
strB = Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 3).Value
```

Where,
If LastRow = 5, strA contains the value of cell A5 and using offset strB contains the value of cell D5